# Ajax, PHP and mysql commenting system

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a comment system for a website using ajax php and mysql. For this I want to send the id of the button clicked to upload a comment (Which will be set to the article name) to an sql database (as well as the comment and some other stuff...)

The system I have at the moment is being rather strange.. If I copy it into jsFiddle it and link to the correct php file on my server it works fine and the id of the button is uploaded to the database.. However if I upload the exact same thing to my website it doesn't work... Here's what I have:

Html form:

```
<form id="addCommentForm"> 
<input type="email" name="email" onchange="checkEmail();" id="email" /> </br>
<div>
<p id="emailerror"> </p>
</div> </br>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> </br>
<input type="text" name="content" id="content" /> </br>
<input type="Button" value="submit" id="Test" onclick="commentSend(this.id);return       false;"/>
</form>
```

The javascript (external):

```
function commentSend(clicked_id) 
{

var email = document.getElementById("email").value //gets the user's email
var username = document.getElementById("username").value //gets the user's username
var content = document.getElementById("content").value //gets the comment content
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  };
xmlhttp.open("GET","commentUpload.php?email=" + email + "&username=" + username +    "&content=" + content + "&articleName="+ clicked_id,true);
xmlhttp.send();

return false;

}
```

And the php:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("myserver","myusername","mypassword");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);

$articleName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['articleName']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['content']);

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$query = "INSERT INTO Comments (id, article, email, name, body)    VALUES (NULL, '" . $articleName ."', '" . $email ."', '" . $username . "', '". $content . "')";

mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

The only thing I can possibly think of is that there is some error with passing the variable this.id to an external javascript file because this is the only value that doesn't get uploaded to the database...

Anyone any ideas!?

Comment: What does Firebug say when you run it on your site?

Comment: I don't use firebug... Gimme a sec I'll download and see what it says

Comment: Welcome to SO, if this is homework please tag as such, you'll get less of a reaming for doing things in the way you have. Teachers out there today simply suck and you shouldn't be blamed for it.

Comment: What sample comment text are you using? One guess is that your sample text is too long and article name is being pushed off. Try using POST data instead of GET to get around any url length issues.

Comment: Ok scrap that... apparently it's just not working with my version of safari... :/ I'm on a beta version can anyone confirm for me if this works on the most recent safari full release?

Comment: Louis I'm actually just starting out teaching myself... Is there anywhere you can point me to correct my mistakes? I'm using w3schools.com tutorials to learn... Is there anything better out there?

Comment: jquery will save you a lot of time with the javascript here. W3schools is a great place to start, just remember: it's for beginners to get up to speed. Best way to learn, after you have your foundation there, is to browse the php and javascript tags here at StackOverflow

Comment: @simonthumper Don't use w3schools tutorials as that gets you deprecated stuff like the `mysql_*` functions. If you're just starting, you need to go straight to PDO (or mysqli...) and you need to get a tutorial that was written less than 10 years ago :-)

Comment: @JoeCortopassi and jeroen thank you both for the good advice! I shall look into what you have both said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not encoding your variables for use in a query string.

What you can do to solve that, is using `encodeURIComponent` (for all values...) like:

```
var content = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("content").value);
```